# directshow, insert text scrolling and image bmp in graph

Tags: video, directshow, freepascal, dspack

I use dspack for free pascal, I created a graph in GraphEdit, now I want to put in the video of the scrolling text and image bmp fixed.
SampleGrabber does this? or should I use the DMO filter? 
I seek a useful tip, to continue my work.
I must do this before VMR because my video output in decklink card.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sample Grabber provides access to data being streamed. Sample Grabber does not overlay text specifically but having raw video access you can modify bits and apply the overlay you need. You will either write all code that converts text into blendable bits of compatible video format, or more likely you want to convert frames of video into something compatible with image APIs (GDI, .NET Graphics etc.), do the overlaying, then convert data back.

See related questions that shed light on the mentioned options:

- [News Marquee over analog TV stream - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638682/news-marquee-over-analog-tv-stream-c-sharp)
- [text overlay issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156654/text-overlay-issue)

Comment: thanks you Roman, very difficult for me. I seek a filter free to do this. I have not found in Google.